# Merge large datatable very slow

Tags: c#, performance, merge, datatable, slowdown

Please check the below code i have large datatables of size 500 to 1000 rows system took around 10 to 12 second to merge datatable.
can you please assist me how to improve datatable merge .and make it fast.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DsResult.Length; i++)
        {
            if (DsResult[i] != null)
            {

                DsFinalResult.Tables[1].Merge(DsResult[i].Tables[2]);
                DsFinalResult.Tables[2].Merge(DsResult[i].Tables[2]);
                DsFinalResult.Tables[3].Merge(DsResult[i].Tables[3]);
                DsFinalResult.Tables[4].Merge(DsResult[i].Tables[4]);
                DsFinalResult.Tables[5].Merge(DsResult[i].Tables[5]);
                DsFinalResult.Tables[6].Merge(DsResult[i].Tables[6]);
                DsFinalResult.Tables[7].Merge(DsResult[i].Tables[7]);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why you have to use `Copy`? That will always create a new DataTable with the same schema and costraints and then fill it with all rows of the source table. Can't you use the source table directly?

Comment: I have try this too but still same it took time .is there any other ways for this

Comment: Not without further infromations, why you have 8 tables that you have to merge with 8 others? Maybe the whole process and the datamodel can be improved.

Comment: All the datatables contains diff informations first i have some data then again by calling some service i get other data and merge them with origianl but  when the size is more  it takes time

Comment: why you even have a `DataSet[] DsResult`?

Comment: DAta is from diff source so i use dataset []

Comment: Why does your `DsFinalResult` have an array of `Tables`? Do they already contain data before you do the `Merge`? Did you mean for the `DsResult[i].Tables` indexes to have `2` repeated twice? Does the key values in the `DsFinalResult` and `DsResult` overlap so you need to `Merge` rows or could you just append?

Comment: DsFinalResult already contains data and  DsResult[i] get data from diff source  and merge to dsFinalResult